# View is reloaded after a http request in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I want to submit data to an API using POST method without reloading the view. Whether success or error, my view gets reloaded after running it.

I'm using this function to submit data to an API:

```
$scope.addObject = function (data) {
    Object.add(data).then(function (response) {
        $scope.isSubmitting = false;
        if (response !== null)
            toaster.pop(response.status, response.status, response.message);
        return false;
    });
};
```

it uses the following service:

```
.factory('Object', function ($http, $rootScope) {
    var object = {},
        url = $rootScope.apiUrl;

    object.add = function (data) {
        return $http({
            url: url + '/object/add',
            method: 'POST',
            params: data
        })
        .then(function(response) { 
            return response.data;
        });
    };

    return object;
});
```

Here's the HTML of the form.

```
<form class="object-form" ng-submit="addObject(objectData)">
    <select name="type" ng-model="objectData.type">
        […]
    </select>
    <button type="submit">OK</button>
</form>
```

The form runs just fine, it's not submitting the page. Just the view gets reloaded.

How can I avoid reloading the view?

---

**UPDATE**

If request is successful (status = 200), it doesn't reload the view.

Comment: please provide the HTML for the form.

Comment: updated with HTML for the form, although even calling the function from other elements i still get my form reloaded.

Comment: Have you tried using `ng-click` on the button instead of using `ng-submit` ? Sorry, not sure if that's what you meant by calling the function from other elements. **EDIT** if the form doesn't reload on 200, maybe it has to do with the uncaught error? Try adding a `.catch`.

Answer (score 0):

So, the problem was coming from another place:

There was an interceptor that was reloading the view if the response was an error.

I'm putting it as an answer, cause it's the second time an interceptor causes me a problem, so, if someone gets here, get to know that you should check interceptors.